# Print some specific text from file name to dwg using mtext

Tags: c#, autocad

I have one dwg file its name is **534-W1A-R1.dwg** i want to print only **W1A-R1** using MText on my dwg file.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("534-W1A-R1.dwg").Substring(fileName.IndexOf('-') + 1)
```

returns "W1A-R1"

Or, using Regular expressions:

```
Regex.Match("534-W1A-R1.dwg", @"-(.+)\.").Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: According to your first code when it gives me "W1A-R1" can i split it again in W1A and R1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Databse` class to extract it's file name. Then as usual - create new `MText` and add to the `ModelSpace` `BlockTableRecord`.

```
[CommandMethod("AddFileNameText")]
public static void AddFileNameText()
{
    Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;

    var db = acDoc.Database;
    using (Transaction transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        ObjectId idModelSpace = SymbolUtilityServices.GetBlockModelSpaceId(db);

        BlockTableRecord modelSpace =
            transaction.GetObject(idModelSpace, OpenMode.ForWrite) as
            BlockTableRecord;

        MText acMText = new MText();
        acMText.SetDatabaseDefaults();

        string strFilePath = db.Filename; //c:\534-W1A-R1.dwg
        strFilePath = 
            System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFilePath); //534-W1A-R1

        //Do ANY text processing            
        if (strFilePath.IndexOf('-') > 0)
            strFilePath = strFilePath.Substring(
                strFilePath.IndexOf('-') + 1); //W1A-R1

        acMText.Contents = strFilePath;

        modelSpace.AppendEntity(acMText);
        transaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acMText, true);

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about if file name is change according to project?

Comment: @Ajjags What do you mean?